# is there any way to generate image url for og:image using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$mainframe->addCustomHeadTag('<meta property="og:image" content="xxxxxxxxxx"/>');
```

I am trying to add the facebook parameters to every page. I am using joomla cms and I am writing a plugin. But I have not idea about how to generate the image urls ? Is there a way. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

just put there URL

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoururl.com/yourimage.php"/>
```

and generate whatever you want from that

Comment: I want completly wrong about the fundamentals, sorry to bother you. Anyway my problem solved..